# Flow server undesired restarts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, yarnpkg, flowtype

Running `yarn flow` in iTerm2 (macOS 11, zsh) starts the server up normally.  Once it finishes the initial check, running `yarn flow` again is lightning fast, as expected.

However, if I then kickoff the githook in our codebase which simply runs `yarn -s flow` it **always** restarts the server again to do the full check. Is there some sort of configuration for flow, or yarn or the shell that I've overlooked?

Comment: have you checked on another machine? Flow server should start and keep running indefinitely for the most part. If you use vscode, there is an option to kill the process when you close the app so that may be doing it, but I'm not sure what your steps are to reproduce so just putting this out there.

Comment: @Brianzchen  A few of my colleagues working on the same project haven't had this issue with their machines.  The only potential 'clue' that I've come across is that the githook is written in bash, but I'm running zsh and IntelliJ WebStorm. Same thing happens whether I run the githook in a terminal inside or outside Webstorm, or use their VCS commit function.